# Transforming a filename with 'tr' using RegEx doesn't work

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, tr

I want to use the `tr` command to rename something like `filename.ext` to `someName.ext`.

To do that I've tried

```
echo "filename.ext" | tr -c ".a-z" "someName"`
```

to replace the *complement* (`-c`) of the filename extension (specified as period, followed by lower-case letters) with the new basename.

However, it does not work - `tr` isn't recognizing it as a complement of a period followed by small case alphabets to be replaced by something else.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa The question is. Do you have a file or bunch of files that you want to rename? What is your end goal?

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Yes I've got a bunch of files in a directory that I'd like to rename. Therefore, I tried doing some string manipulation before going ahead with mv command and all. But does it matter if I'm gonna rename a bunch of files?

Comment: Do you want to remove/change the extension of file? FOr this purpose in `bash` there are much simple ways...

Comment: AbhishekAUdupa are you aware of `man` to read documentation? For example `man tr`. If not, it's a useful resource

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa it would matter in terms of wether a loop is needed or not. If you want to rename a bunch of files you can so this using bash or `prename` utility.

Comment: If you want to rename files using regular expressions, use the perl `rename` utility (**not** the `rename` in util-linux, that's a completely different and incompatible program).  Depending on your distro, this might be called `rename`, `prename`, `file-rename`, `perl-rename`, or similar.  Run `rename -V` and if it mentions perl or File::Rename, that's perl rename.   There are [lots of questions and answers about perl rename on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=perl+rename) which provide usage examples and explanations of how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tr` command does not use regex.  It uses character ranges and lists and does one for one character replacements or deletions.

For example, `tr A-Z a-z` would translate uppercase letters to lowercase letters.

If you want to replace by regex, use `sed` instead of tr.